# python maya: How do i create a linear bezier curve?

Tags: python, maya

Using python in maya how do I create a linear spline that is not curved or smooth? I tried a few different options and I'm unclear how to do this.

This is the first step in a script I'm trying to create. I'm trying to just create something similar to the image below.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.curve(bezier=True, p=[(0, 0, 0), (3, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (9, 9, 9)] )
```

[image]

Comment: I believe if you make the control points equal to the end points, the Bezier segment will be a straight line. E.g. `p=[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (9, 9, 9), (9, 9, 9)]`

Comment: Wouldn't a "linear spline that is not curved or smooth" just be a line (segment)? Or perhaps a polyline (sequence of line segments), given your example?

Comment: I posted an image to further explain what im trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a linear curve you don't want bezier; you just want a degree 1 curve:

```
cmds.curve(d=1, p=[(0, 0, 0), (3, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (9, 9, 9)] )
```

If you really need that to be a bezier, the mel procedure nurbsCurveToBezier will convert it:

```
import maya.mel as mel
cmds.curve(d=1, p=[(0, 0, 0), (3, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (9, 9, 9)] )
maya.mel.eval("nurbsCurveToBezier");
```

Comment: Steve you are a genius. I'm going to have to donate some money towards you if you keep answering my questions, you'll have to let me!